# Is there a reason why the actors sound exactly the same as their anime counterparts in the live action movies?

Tags: death-note, voice-acting

For the first time today I watched *Death Note* and *Death Note the Last name* (real life movies) and I noticed that the actors sound exactly the same as their anime counterparts. Why is this?

E.g. Light Yagami in the real life movie sounded exactly the same as in the anime. Is this just me?

Answers are appreciated. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Going through [Wikipedia's list of Death Note voice actors for the live action movie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Death_Note_%28film%29#Cast), it seems that there is not much overlap (if any) between the Japanese actors and the *Japanese* voice actors for Death Note.

However, going through the first couple entries of the list, it seems that at least a number of the *English* voice actors for the Death Note anime also functioned as voice actors for the dubs of the live action movies. While this isn't true for some characters (e.g. Naomi Misora) this definitely seems to hold for a number of the voice actors for the major anime characters.